# Error: The type Image<TColor, TDepth>' exists in both 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.3.0.2824 and Emgu.CV, Version=2.2.1.1150

Tags: c#, opencv, dll

I am using Emug cv Version=3.3.0.2824 in my image processing project.
After that i want to use other Version of Emug cv so i used this  Version=2.2.1.1150.

So i removed all references of the old version (Version=3.3.0.2824)Then after that i used the new version (Version=2.2.1.1150)

but after i made build for my project these errors are displayed 
[image: Errors]

I am trying to solve them by doing the following steps :
remove all dlls from project folder Then
clean the solution then
rebuild again

but it did not work

**The Question**
How can i remove the oldest emug cv dlls from my project so i can use the new version of emug cv after that ?

Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use both references from NuGet and dll files

```
Uninstall Nuget package
```